# Microsoft Bot- Looping with same answer even input is different

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

We are developing a library bot using Microsoft bot framework.

We have

```
Intent : BookSearch
Entiry : BookName, BookAuthor
```

When I search "I need a java book", it understands that 'java' is an entity, and provides the java book with other details.

My question is, Once I received the java book details, I want to issue the book, so again, when we ask "Issue me book Java", here it conflicts and will show java book details again, like if its going in loop.

Please help us in this scenario, how can we determine different context in our question?

Code :

```
 [LuisIntent("BookSearch")]
    public async Task BookSearch(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        if (result.Entities.Any())
        {
            DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect();
            string combindedString = string.Empty;
            string mysqlQuery = string.Empty;

            foreach (var item in result.Entities)
            {
                switch (item.Type.ToString())
                {
                    case "BookAuthor":

                        break;
                    case "BookName":

                        break;
                    case "BookIssue":

                        break;
                    default:                         

                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Which book are you searching.");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

    }
```

Here BookName and BookIssue are the entities, 
So when we ask "I need java book" => It should go into the BookName entity to provide book details.
When we ask "Issue me java book" => It should go into the BookIssue entity to process issuing formality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A code example may help us.

Comment: @Svekke, I have edited question to add code

Comment: @PareshBijarane Can you post the code to the Intent where the book issuing is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

`BookIssue` should be its own intent & method. In your code you appear to be treating `BookIssue` as an entity.

Do what you did for `BookSearch` but with the utterances and logic you want to have in your `BookIssue` method.

Right now you're "stuck" in your `BookSearch` intent because you have not defined another one and LUIS is matching those utterances to search.

By the way, for this application you might want to consider using [FormFlow](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html).

Comment: Thanks Anna Zietlow

If we go with FormFlow, how can we show no of books, if books count more than 50 or 100. As we fetching data from real time system, and there may have so many matching books for our search.

Comment: Sorry, I am guessing FormFlow is probably better suited for your BookIssue intent. Your search one does sound too complicated for it